# Delete XML element in php using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Hi guys i have a simple XML document :

```
<iPhone>
 <enAttente>
  <UDID>value</UDID>
  <adresse>value</adresse>
 </enAttente>
 <enAttente>
  <UDID>value</UDID>
  <adresse>value</adresse>
 </enAttente>
</iPhone>
```

I want to delete **<enAttente>** where **<adresse>** = **myValue** this is what i do :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;   
$doc->load('./folder/myFile.xml');  
if ($doc)
{
    $domNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagname('enAttente');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
        foreach ($domNodeList as $domElement ) {
         $authors = $domElement->getElementsByTagName( "adresse" );
         $author = $authors->item(0)->nodeValue;

         if ($author == "myValue")
         {
             echo"Founded ! Delete this node ! -- ";
             // HOW CAN I DELETE this <enAttente> !!
         }
        }
    }

    $doc->saveXML();      
}
```

Can someone telle how to delete element  when i have found the one to delete ? 
thank you very much !

Comment: Nope because i have seen this post but i couldn't managed to it ! thanks

Comment: can you show the exact code you used that "does not work"?

Comment: Well i have try so many things like : 
 $domElement->removeChild($authors->item(0));
$author->parentNode->removeChild($author);
$domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);

Comment: Note that ``saveXML()`` doesn't write the file: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php It just returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need

```
$domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);
```

Comment: Oh my GOD THANK YOU SO MUCH FLORIS !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You mentioned in your comment that this was one of the things you had tried… but I'm glad it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is some working code:

```
<?php
$file = './folder/myFile.xml';
$doc = new DOMDocument;   
$doc->load($file);  
if ($doc)
{
    $domNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagname('enAttente');

    foreach ($domNodeList as $domElement ) {
        $authors = $domElement->getElementsByTagName('adresse');
        $firstNode = $authors->item(0);

        $author = $firstNode->nodeValue;
        if ($author == "myValue")
        {
            echo "Founded ! Delete this node ! -- ";
            $doc->documentElement->removeChild($domElement);
        }
    }

    $doc->save($file);      
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to combine your two answers into one?…